# php push 1 key to end of array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Say I have an array:

```
$k = array('1', 'a', '2', '3');
```

I would like to push 'a' to the end of the array. So it would become:

```
$k = array('1', '2', '3', 'a');
```

Is there any efficient way to do this?

Comment: Are you wanting to sort the array alphabetically? Or is your general case that you always want the second element of the array pushed to the back?

Comment: This is an especially poor/vague [mcve] and I find it to be Unclear and inviting answers that fundamentally execute different techniques but can still generate the desired result.  For this reason, this page should be closed until clarified.  A good sample array will have enough complexity to differentiate correct answers from incorrect answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try PHPs [natsort](http://php.net/natsort) function:

```
<?php

$k = array('1', 'a', '2', '3');
var_dump($k);
natsort($k);
var_dump($k);
```

Outputs:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "3"
}
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "3"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "a"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean you want to sort the array. You can use PHP's `sort()` function [see the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) for options (like sorting type, you'll probably need `SORT_STRING`).

Answer (score 1):

```
$k = array('1', 'a', '2', '3');

$varToMove = $k[1];

unset($k[1]);
$k[] = $varToMove;

var_dump($k);
```

You'll get:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "3"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "a"
}
```

Just note that key `1` is missing at the moment. Not sure if you care about them though.